# Spring Boot ServletRegistrationBean and Deployment to External Tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot, servlet-3.0

Recently I found the possibility to add my own servlet bean to MVC using the ServletRegistrationBean, which comes with Spring Boot. But the documentation seems to suggest that this is only for embedded servlet containers: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html
My simple question is: can the ServletRegistrationBean be used only with embedded containers or also when deploying a war to an external Tomcat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ServletRegistrationBean` will also work with external Tomcat, in fact that's exactly how Boot registers its own `DispatcherServlet` when you deploy a Boot app to Tomcat (or any other Servlet container).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems when deploying spring boot war file to weblogic. The servlet is able to registered with the support of Servlet 3.x web container. but weblogic is trying to create new servlet instance instance of the servlet bean.

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
public GraphQLServlet graphQLServlet(GraphQLSchemaProvider schemaProvider, ExecutionStrategyProvider executionStrategyProvider) {
    return new SimpleGraphQLServlet(schemaProvider, executionStrategyProvider, objectMapperConfigurer, listeners, instrumentation, errorHandler, contextBuilder, graphQLRootObjectBuilder);
}

@Bean
ServletRegistrationBean graphQLServletRegistrationBean(GraphQLServlet servlet) {
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, graphQLServletProperties.getServletMapping());
}
```

and the weblogic throws the exceptions like this:

```
<Oct 2, 2017 4:08:31 PM SGT> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101125> <[ServletContext@344074943[app:cpapps-gra3.1]] Error occurred while instantiating servlet: "simpleGraphQLServlet".
java.lang.InstantiationException: graphql.servlet.SimpleGraphQLServlet
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebComponentContributor.getNewInstance(WebComponentContributo
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebComponentContributor.getNewInstance(WebComponentContributo
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebComponentContributor.createServletInstance(WebComponentCon
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.newServletInstanceIfNece
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: graphql.servlet.SimpleGraphQLServlet.<init>()
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebComponentContributor.getNewInstance(WebComponentContributo
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebComponentContributor.getNewInstance(WebComponentContributo
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebComponentContributor.createServletInstance(WebComponentCon
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

It seems that the web requests directly go to the weblogic rather than spring dispatcher servlet.

But it's tricky to see that the same war file can be deployed and run in tomcat without any error.